# How can I generate swagger based off of existing postman collection?

Tags: postman, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

I am developing a REST API. during development I have used postman (chrome extension) to use and document my API. It is a wonderful tool and I have most of my API endpoints in it. 
However, as we near release I would like to document this API in swagger, how would I do that? Is there a way that I can generate swagger based off of the postman export?

Comment: For C#/DotNet, see these two: 1.[]c# - How to generate JSON Postman Collections from a WebApi2 project using WebApi HelpPages that are suitable for import - Stack Overflow ; ; stackoverflow.com/questions/23158379/ ; ;  ; 2.[]; ;  X.Introducing the Azure API Apps Tools for Visual Studio 2013 - The Visual Studio Blog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs ; ; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/03/24/introducing-the-azure-api-apps-tools-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx

Comment: You can use postman2openapi on the web: https://kevinswiber.github.io/postman2openapi/

Comment: https://metamug.com/util/postman-to-swagger/ is most updated tool.

Comment: you can use postman to swagger online tool  https://www.workversatile.com/postman-to-swagger

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Someone posted this link (and deleted it?): http://restunited.com/

It accepts postman JSON and converts it to swagger. This seems to be what I was looking for.

Comment: RestUnited is only free if one has <=5 endpoints per API and <=3 APIs.

Comment: The export (to postman collection or swagger spec) has no limitation. The limitation you mentioned is only for generating SDKs and documentation.

Comment: The best option for the OP is https://apimatic.io/transformer

Comment: I just tried to import the default postman echo collection on restunited and it wouldn't work.  Maybe they haven't been keeping up to date with postman?

Comment: it doesn't work for new versions.

Comment: Not able to find the upload postman collection option, maybe they have stopped the support.

Answer (score 116):

As of 2022 my recommendation is the excellent Rust/Wasm tool from Kevin Swiber, which is available online, as a Rust crate and as an npm module. https://kevinswiber.github.io/postman2openapi/

*[APIMatic API Transformer](https://apimatic.io/transformer) can process a Postman collection (v1 or v2) as an input format and produce Swagger 1.2 or 2.0, and now OpenAPI 3.0.0 as output.*

*It has its own API and a Web front-end, and also a [command-line version](https://github.com/apimatic/apimatic-cli).*

Comment: Note that the site requires an account to be created to use.

Comment: now supports swagger 2.1

Comment: This works like a charm when I tried to convert my  postman V2.1 json to swagger 2.0. But they ask you to sign up first.

Comment: I have signed up and they have provided me a 14 days trial period, not sure if I would be able to convert the Postman collection to Swagger post the trial period is over.

Comment: Why not try a free online converter like any other converter. All it takes is some javascript https://metamug.com/util/postman-to-swagger/

Comment: this doesn't work :)

Comment: I now recommend https://github.com/kevinswiber/postman2openapi

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but even on the github.io page there's a big link saying "Fork Me" so there's no need to signup for anything.  Both the io and com links show how to download the binaries and run them locally without needing to create an account.  Are you prompted from the command line???

Answer (score 14):

You can use
https://github.com/stoplightio/api-spec-converter
with code

```
var transformer = require('api-spec-transformer');

var postmanToSwagger = new transformer.Converter(transformer.Formats.POSTMAN, transformer.Formats.SWAGGER);

postmanToSwagger.loadFile('/path/to/your.json.postman_collection', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
    return;
  }

  postmanToSwagger.convert('yaml')
    .then(function(convertedData) {
      // convertedData is swagger YAML string
      console.log(convertedData);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: This only works with Postman V1 collections though!