# How to show query parameters in HTML reports generated by newman?

Tags: postman, swagger, openapi, newman

I've added some documentation for my API in Postman and I'm using [`newman`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman) and [`htmlextra`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-htmlextra) to generate reports. Along with the request URL, the documentation lists the *query parameters* (`id`, `name`) below.

[image: POSTMAN API Documentation]

However, on generating reports, the query parameter is not displayed.

[image: NEWMAN Exported Report]

1. **Is there a way to show the query parameters, like in swagger?**
   [image: swaggerUI Example]
2. **Is there a reporter that will convert POSTMAN Collection v2.1 File to swaggerUI?**

Comment: W/r/t #2, see [How can I generate Swagger based off of existing Postman collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31299098/113116)